# Explicit copy constructor

Tags: c++, copy-constructor, assignment-operator, stdstring, explicit

I have extended std::string to fulfil my needs of having to write custom function build into string class called **CustomString**

I have defined constructors:

```
    class CustomString : public std::string {
    public:
        explicit CustomString(void);
        explicit CustomString(const std::string& str);
        explicit CustomString(const CustomString& customString);
        //assignment operator
        CustomString& operator=(const CustomString& customString);
    ... };
```

In the third constructor (copy constructor) and assignment operator, whose definition is:

```
CustomString::CustomString(const CustomString& customString):
    std::string(static_cast<std::string>(customString)) 
{}
CustomString& CustomString::operator=(const CustomString& customString){
    this->assign(static_cast<std::string>(customString));
    return *this;
}
```

First since this is an "explicit"; meaning an explicit cast is needed to assign to another CustomString object; it's complaining about the assignment.

```
CustomString s = CustomString("test");
```

I am not sure where exactly is casting needed explicitly.

The code works alright if copy constructor is not explicit but I would like to know and implement explicit definition instead of "guessing proper cast".

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The explicit copy constructor means that the copy constructor will not be called implicitly, which is what happens in the expression:

```
CustomString s = CustomString("test");
```

This expression literally means: create a temporary `CustomString` using the constructor that takes a `const char*`. Implicitly call the copy constructor of `CustomString` to copy from that temporary into `s`.

Now, if the code was correct (i.e. if the copy constructor was not explicit), the compiler would avoid the creation of the temporary and elide the copy by constructing `s` directly with the string literal. But the compiler must still check that the construction can be done and fails there.

You can call the copy constructor explicitly:

```
CustomString s( CustomString("test") );
```

But I would recommend that you avoid the temporary altogether and just create `s` with the `const char*`:

```
CustomString s( "test" );
```

Which is what the compiler would do anyway...

Comment: Oh yea I completely understand your answer (and it is proper answer and I have marked it as best answer) but how would I achieve

`CustomString s = customStringObjectOnStack;` for example?

Comment: @mkhan3189 you can achieve CustomString s = customStringObjectOnStack if and only if copy-ctor will not be explicit. For second question, kDelimited is CustomString or something else? And + your function is const, so c.append(static_cast<const std::string&>(*this)) will works.

Comment: @ForEveR Yea Thanks for that. I got the answer myself. kDelimiter is CustomString constant object, yes. `c.append(static_cast<std::string>(*this))` works for implicit copy-ctor declaration. So all good. This thread can be closed.

Comment: @mkhan3189: You can achieve `CustomString s = customStringObjectOnStack;` by instead of implicitly using that copy constructor with the `=` syntax, you explicitly call the copy constructor: `CustomString s( customStringObjectOnStack );`

Answer (score 7):

Deriving from std::string is not safe, as std::string has no virtual destructor. As to your question - your copy constructors should not be explicit, to allow for such usage as:

```
CustomString s = "test";
```

Also I have no idea why you would want to declare a copy-constructor as explicit, as it is not needed.
An explicit copy-constructor will work only if you declare your CustomString object as:

```
CustomString s(CustomString("test"));
```

Comment: @ildjarn: why lazy? It is correct (not optimal, but correct) tackles the problem and provides a solution...

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas when ildjarn posting comment, answer was rather shorter.

Comment: Thanks and nice answer but this is lazy because I have asked this to improve my way of writing code instead of just getting thing done. Thanks anyways :)

Comment: As long as the OP _only_ uses `CustomString`s and doesn't, say, try to `delete` a `new CustomString` through a `std::string` pointer, is there _really_ anything unsafe about this derivation?

Comment: *“As long as [...], is there anything unsafe?”*. Unless you have the means to enforce the conditions reliably and consistently over time, including coworker's code and wherever this might get copy-pasted to in the future, the answer to that question is always yes. No matter what's in the "[...]".

Answer (score 0):

It seems current gcc won't invoke the copy constructor tested in gcc 8.2(MinGW.org GCC-8.2.0-5)，and will utilize to call constructor directly For X1

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;


class X1 {
public:

    X1() {
        cout<< "invoke constructor" << endl;
    }; 

    explicit X1(const X1 &obj)  { 
        cout << "invoke copy constructor" << endl;
    };

    X1(X1&& obj)  {
        cout << "invoke move constructor" << endl;
    };

    X1& operator=(const X1 &obj) {
        cout << "invoke value assign constructor " << endl;
        if(this == &obj) {
            return *this;
        }
        return *this;
    };

    X1& operator=(const X1 && obj) {
        cout << "invoke move value assign constructor " << endl;
        if(this == &obj) {
            return *this;
        }
        return *this;

    };

    ~X1() {
        cout << "invoke deconstruct" << endl;
    };



};

int main() {
//    X1 l1(1);
//    X1 l3(2);
    X1 l4 = X1();

    return 0;
}
```