# Why are vector contents changed after the method scope finishes?

Tags: c++, for-loop, vector, scope

The following dummy program mimics the behavior of another program I'm troubleshooting.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class A
{
public:
    std::vector<int> data;

    void DoTheThing()
    {
        while (data.size() < 10) {
            data.push_back(1);
        }
    }
};

class B
{
public:
    std::vector<A> objs;

    B()
    {
        A one, two, three;
        objs.push_back(one);
        objs.push_back(two);
        objs.push_back(three);
    }

    void DoTheThing()
    {
        for (auto obj: objs) {
            obj.DoTheThing();
            std::cout << "DEBUG length during=" << obj.data.size() << std::endl;
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    B b;
    b.DoTheThing();
    for (auto obj : b.objs) {
        std::cout << "DEBUG length  after=" << obj.data.size() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

I compile and run as:

```
$ g++ -Wall --std=c++11 -o test test.cpp
$ ./test
DEBUG length during=10
DEBUG length during=10
DEBUG length during=10
DEBUG length  after=0
DEBUG length  after=0
DEBUG length  after=0
$
```

For some reason the state of the `A` objects in `b`'s `objs` vector is changing between the `b.DoTheThing()` call and the subsequent print statements. My question is **what is happening**? Are the `A` object `data` vectors going out of scope somehow and being deleted, or perhaps the entire `A` objects? It seems like a scoping issue--perhaps even a trivially simple one--but it's been long enough since I programmed in C++ that I'm not sure. How can I make the contents of the `data` vectors persist after the call to `b.DoTheThing()` in the other methods?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> "For some reason the state of the `A` objects in b's `objs` `vector` is changing between the `b.DoTheThing()` call and the subsequent print statements. **My question is what is happening?**"

```
void DoTheThing()
{
  for(auto obj : objs)
   // ^^^^^^^ receive by value due to implicit copy
```

You are actually making a separate copy of `objs` into individual temporary `obj`s. Those temporaries are destroyed after the `B::DoThething()` finishes. To avoid the copies, use **reference**:

```
  for(auto& obj : objs)
   // ^^^^^^^ receive by reference
```

The same is true for the similar loop in the `main()` as well.

---

Real question can be: *"How to avoid such accidents?"*

If you can afford, then **make the copy constructor as `explicit` to avoid implicit copying**:

```
class A {
public:
  A () = default;      
  explicit A(const A&) = default;  // implicit copy is avoided
  A (A&&) = default;  // to avoid RVO related issues
  ...
};
```

Here is a [demo](http://ideone.com/QKbh0w), which shows how the `explicit` generates *compilation error* to catch the problem in the `for` loop which accidentally makes copies.

---

The `explicit` brings its own syntax limitations. Some of them can be solved & some cannot. Refer following question for 1 such issue (& how it's solved):

[What is the effect of 'explicit' keyword on the Return Value Optimization (RVO)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38720228/what-is-the-effect-of-explicit-keyword-on-the-return-value-optimization-rvo)

Comment: Making a copy constructor `explicit` is likely to cause other problems. It's better to just learn the language to understand where copies are made, and avoid it them if needed.

Comment: @JonathanWakely, 1 of such known issues is the RVO thing. That can be solved in certain situations, which I have updated in the answer. Yes, `explicit` comes with its own limitation, but I find them worthy. I had been into exactly this situation few weeks back & it was really difficult to debug. We can also have a `#ifdef/#endif`s & create a `#define conditional_explicit explicit` under it. This can be useful to eventual check of any such copies & revert back to normal.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in the range for loop:

```
void DoTheThing()
    {
        for (auto obj: objs) {
            obj.DoTheThing();
            std::cout << "DEBUG length during=" << obj.data.size() << std::endl;
        }
    }
```

You are copying the `A` object and doing the modification in the copy, not in the original one.

Change it to:

```
for (auto& obj: objs) {
  ...
}
```

and it should work as expected.

Answer (score 2):

You have to change your for loops as follows:

```
for (auto& obj : b.objs)
```

In this way you handle the actual object in the container by reference. 
If you declare it as:

```
for (auto obj : b.objs)
```

`obj` will be a copy

Comment: Awesome. I knew it was simple. Thanks!

Comment: you can have fun with `for_each` as well as next step :-)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of receive by value you should use receive by reference.

```
for (auto obj : b.objs) {
        std::cout << "DEBUG length  after=" << obj.data.size() << std::endl;
    }
```

Above piece of code is receive by value, Change it to

```
for (auto& obj : b.objs) {
        ........
    }
```