# Copy constructor and overloaded addition operator

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, bigint, explicit, explicit-constructor

I am reviewing operator overloading in C++. Just for fun I am implementing a `BigInt` class.

The first operator I want to overload for it is the **addition operator**. I have decided to overload this operator as a friend non-member function. Here's a MWE of this code:

```
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class BigInt{
 public:
  friend BigInt operator+(const BigInt &bi1, const BigInt &bi2);

  BigInt() {}
  explicit BigInt(const std::string &in) {
    if (in.size() != 0) {
      for (auto cc = in.rbegin(); cc != in.rend(); ++cc) {
        value_.push_back(*cc);
      }
    }
  }
  std::string value() {
    std::string actual_value{};  // Reversed string.
    for (auto cc = value_.rbegin(); cc != value_.rend(); ++cc) {
      actual_value.push_back(*cc);
    }
    return actual_value;
  }

 private:
  std::string value_;  // String of digits as characters.
};

BigInt operator+(const BigInt &bi1, const BigInt &bi2) {
  BigInt result{};

  result.value_ = "4421";
  return result;
}

int main() {
  std::cout << "Test addition operator... ";
  std::string number{"1234"};  // Number 1,234.
  BigInt mm(number);
  std::string number_ten{"10"};  // Number 10.
  BigInt nn(number_ten);

  BigInt mm_nn = mm + nn;

  std::string expected_result{"1244"};  // 1,234 + 10 = 1,244.
  assert(mm_nn.value() == expected_result);
  std::cout << "ok." << std::endl;
}
```

This code mocks the behavior of the addition. It compiles and runs. Yet when I add a copy constructor for the `BigInt` class, this codes stops working. I.e. if I add this to the class declaration:

`explicit BigInt(const BigInt &in): value_(in.value_) {}`

The code does not even compile. The addition function as coded returns a copy of a constructed instance of `BigInt`. For this a copy constructor must be defined. If I do not define it myself, then the compiler will do so. What does the compiler produce that I am not producing with the added copy constructor? Here's the compilation error I get:

```
$ g++ -std=c++14 -g mwe.cpp 
mwe.cpp: In function ‘BigInt operator+(const BigInt&, const BigInt&)’:
mwe.cpp:34:10: error: no matching function for call to ‘BigInt::BigInt(BigInt&)’
   return result;
          ^
mwe.cpp:9:3: note: candidate: BigInt::BigInt()
   BigInt() {}
   ^
mwe.cpp:9:3: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 1 provided
mwe.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
mwe.cpp:44:23: error: no matching function for call to ‘BigInt::BigInt(BigInt)’
   BigInt mm_nn = mm + nn;
                       ^
mwe.cpp:9:3: note: candidate: BigInt::BigInt()
   BigInt() {}
   ^
mwe.cpp:9:3: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 1 provided
```

From it, it seems like the compiler expects a copy constructor that I have not provided. Now... IF I REMOVE the `explicit` keyword, everything works. However, I have seen implementations with explicit copy constructor, for example: [Explicit copy constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11480545/explicit-copy-constructor)

What am I missing? Why can't I make this copy constructor explicit while overloading the addition operator? Should, in general, copy constructors be made explicit?

Comment: Unrelated , you can simply make your parameterised cntor like this: `explicit BigInt(const std::string &in) :value_(in.rbegin(), in.rend()) { }` also there is a function in `<algorithm>` called `std::reverse`.

Comment: in otherwords, you can write this function as: `std::string value() { return std::string(value_.rbegin(), value_.rend()); }`

Comment: The problem is that your copy construct is `explicit`, so `return result;` does not work, you would need `return BigInt{result};`. Simply make your copy-constructor not explicit.

Comment: *"Why can't I make this copy constructor explicit"* - why would you *want* to make it explicit? There are finite, specific reasons one does so, but they're exceptional, not regular, and I see no evidence to support such an exceptional case here. You asked, *"What does the compiler produce that I am not producing*". In reality, you should be asking *"What am I producing that the compiler is not?"*, and the answer is a significantly more restrictive mechanism for invoking copy construction; specifically disqualifying all implicit copying.

Comment: This code compiles correctly with `GCC 4.9.2`. What compiler are you using?

Comment: Nvm, I didn't paste the line with copy constructor.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [explicit copy constructor compile error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29472565/explicit-copy-constructor-compile-error)

Comment: @NO_NAME that's a high possibility for this question.

Comment: @JeJo Sorry, I don't understand. Could you rephrase?

Comment: @NO_NAME The question you linked can be considered as a duplicate. That's what I meant :). BTW Thanks for that.

Comment: @NO_NAME that compiler is nearly 4 years old

Comment: @M.M I just used `cpp.sh`. Anyway, it prints the same error, so it doesn't matter.

Comment: The concept of "explicit" contradicts the concept of copy constructor. It doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Making the copy constructor `explicit` does not make sense. Remove it.

```
BigInt(const BigInt &in): value_(in.value_) {}
```

---

#### Conceptual Problem With `explicit` Copy Constructor

Making a copy constructor `explicit` makes returning an object from a function impossible.

Let's simplify your code to the following:

```
struct BigInt
{
   BigInt() {}
   explicit BigInt(const BigInt &in) {}
};

BigInt operator+(const BigInt &bi1, const BigInt &bi2)
{
   BigInt result;
   return result;
}

int main() {}
```

In the line `return result`, the compiler relies on the copy constructor to return an object. When the copy constructor is explicit, there is no way for a `BigInt` to be constructed as the return value.

Trying to use:

```
BigInt operator+(const BigInt &bi1, const BigInt &bi2)
{
   BigInt result;
   return BigInt(result);
}
```

is futile since that is equivalent to:

```
BigInt operator+(const BigInt &bi1, const BigInt &bi2)
{
   BigInt result;
   BigInt result1(result);
   return result1;
}
```

The problem continues to be there no matter what you do in the function.

Comment: I agree. However, this is weird that compiler cannot find a match for `BigInt::BigInt(BigInt&)`. This error occurs even if you remove `const` from the constructor.

Comment: OK, I get it now. `explicit` forbids compiler to call the constructor implicitly even if there is no type conversion.

Comment: @R Sahu *Why can't I make this copy constructor explicit while overloading the addition operator?* You haven't answered this OPs question.

Comment: @JeJo, added some more details.

Comment: @NO_NAME, the compiler tries to find a `BigInt(BigInt&)` since `BigInt(BigInt const&)` is explicit.

Comment: @RSahu Now, that deserves a UP :). Thanks for your explanation. Well, I actually found the code working with `return BigInt(result);`,  when I use GCC 7.1 or later (see this: https://wandbox.org compiles),  but older does not(see this: https://www.ideone.com/V20olX). However, I didn't get any explanation to understand this. How the later compilers overcome this problem! :(

Comment: @JeJo, RVO might be at play there. IIRC, C++17 has added some clauses that make RVO mandatory in some constructs.

Comment: @JeJo, Return Value Optimization. If I Recall/Remember Correctly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172859/discussion-between-jejo-and-r-sahu).

Comment: Since C++17, if you `return` a prvalue then the prvalue initializes the result object, there are no temporaries. (When the function call initializes a variable, that variable is the result object).  The code samples where you return a prvalue substantially differ from the samples where you return an lvalue.

Comment: @M.M, That does explain the behavior reported by JeJo.

Comment: @M.M Yes, that makes sense.